# MetaMask-iOS-SDK can't connect

Tags: metamask

MetaMask_iOS_SDK to connect MetaMask App, it's work Error?
sdk-version: 0.5.0
MetaMask app-veraion: 7.15.0

nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C2.1.1] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for metamask-sdk-socket.metafi.codefi.network:443

Before, it could be connected, but after the version upgrade, it could not be connected